# How do mammals explore state spaces in reinforcement learning tasks?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, cognitive-modeling, reinforcement-learning

Reinforcement learning is the act of learning how to preform a task given punishment and reward. A "state-space" is the space of choices in a context. When performing a reinforcement learning task, is there an underlying methodology to how mammals (humans, monkeys, rats) explore the state space of a task and has is been embodied in any cognitive models?

Comment: Not sure I understand how research on exploring a "state-space" would differ from research on any other behaviour?  That is, the purpose of such experiments is to learn about animal (and human) behaviour in general, is it not?  Based on the large volume of research on behaviour, I would expect the animal's "exploratory" behaviour to be subject to the same model as any other behaviour - ie, based on its genetics and learning history (nature and nurture), and whatever model predicts behaviour in general...